# Autocomplete en página bootstrap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo un autocomplete de jquery y jquery ui y funciona correctamente.

Al incluirlo en mi página quitandole las dos referencias  de (js/jquery) y (jquery ui), estas ya las incluyo en la pagina con bootstrap y no he logrado que funcione

El formulario es muy básico pero funciona.
No se si con esto sea suficiente para que sepan a que me refiero... Agradezco infinito la ayuda.

[image: Esta imagen carga el formulario que como explico, funciona fuera del index, pero dentro falla....Gracias.]

Saludos.

```
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#buscador").autocomplete({
                source: 'buscador.php',
                select: function(event, ui){
                    $("#resultado").html(
                        '<h2>Detalles del Hotel:</h2>' +
                        'Nombre de Hotel: ' +
                        ui.item.value + '<br>' +
                        'id de Hotel: ' +
                        ui.item.idhotel + '<br>' +
                        'Tarifa OW: ' +
                        ui.item.t1ow + '<br>' +
                        'Tarifa Rt: ' +
                        ui.item.t1rt + '<br>' +
                                    'id de Zona: ' +
                        ui.item.Zona
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!--Formulario-Lun-->
```

Find your hotel or destination
      
      
      
      
        
        
      
      
      
      PAX
      
       1
       2
       3
       4
       5
       6
       7
       8
       9
       10
      
      CURRENCY
      
      MXP
      USD

Comment: ¿Que errores tienes, diseño y/o funcional? Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/96463/edit) para agregar más detalle. Puedes agregar captura de pantalla.

Comment: A mi me parece que no estas cargando los escripts en el orden adecuado. Lo que provoca que cuando se carga el javascript los elementos html todavía no existan y por eso no funciona, Deberías detallar la posición del html respecto al script para poder determinar si efectivamente es este el problema.

Comment: Podria ser pero como deberia ser?... lo he intentado pero no lo logro...gracias

Comment: <!-- Jquery ui-->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>

</body>